# Formula to pull text from one sheet in excel to another to summarize (not numbers)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that has a tab for each research location.  There is a section on the sheet that has several columns. Three of the columns are as follows: 1 lists action items (text)  1 lists who is responsible (text) and 1 lists the due date (date field). The rows in this same "table" represent categories.  In many cases there is an action item only in one or two categories or maybe none at all for some.

I would like to query each tab that represents a research site and pull any action items, the responsible party and date onto another tab so that we can see all action items in one place for all the sites vs. going tab by tab to review.

I thought some sort of IF or VLOOKUP function might work, or some sort of pivot table but because it is text and not numbers I am having a hard time crafting the appropriate formula.  I was also told I could do some sort of reference look up (like putting a word like ACTION at the start of any text I want to find later) but this seems more complicated than it needs to be.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: why would you tag sql here?

Comment: Its what stack overflow suggested, if I knew what I was doing would I be asking this?

Comment: The sql tag is gone.  Regarding the question, my approach on office macros is to always start by using the macro recorder and doing stuff manually.  That gives me some code with which to work.  Afterwards it's then a matter of conditional logic and loops and whatnot.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to do a [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx). Copy a unique identifier to a worksheet and vlookup the fields you want to get them onto your sheet.

Comment: VLookup can be complicated for novice users. My hunch is VLookup is all you need. Look at the VLookup syntax closely and use it. It should work

Comment: what would be the 'lookup value' when using VLOOKUP?? Action items can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think VLOOKUP can solve your problem. You definitely need VBA so something like this will get you going. Make a new sheet called as Summary and put this code in the sheet:

```
Sub SummarizeSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Summary").Activate
 Range("A2").Select
 For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
     If ws.Range("A2") <> "" Then 'A2 is blank means no action items found so go to next worksheet
      ws.Range("A2:C100000").Copy 'Adjust your range here
      ActiveSheet.Paste Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)' Paste the copied range
    End If
     End If
Next ws
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

You have to adjust the code to suit your needs. Assumption here is your action items starts with cell A2 and responsible person and due date are in cell B2 and C2 respectively.

Comment: Thanks I am working with this solution right now and think it is the solve!

Comment: let me know if you face any problem